# Hurled it on/to the floor

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions

He went over to the mirror, ripped it off the wall, and hurled it on/to the floor, shattering it.

Which one of "on" and "to" is correct?

Comment: Both are correct.

Comment: I thought these kinds of questions were not allowed....

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct, but [*to* is much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hurled%20it%20%2A%20the%20floor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Churled%20it%20%2A%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhurled%20it%20to%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhurled%20it%20on%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhurled%20it%20upon%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhurled%20it%20at%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhurled%20it%20onto%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhurled%20it%20across%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhurled%20it%20against%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0) in American English.  We usually use *to* with verbs expressing motion, like *hurled*, but *on* or *onto* are also acceptable.  Different prepositions can be more or less idiomatic to use with different verbs: compare the graphs for "[dropped it * the floor](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dropped%20it%20%2A%20the%20floor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cdropped%20it%20%2A%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdropped%20it%20on%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdropped%20it%20to%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdropped%20it%20onto%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdropped%20it%20upon%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdropped%20it%20in%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0)", "[threw it * the floor](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=threw%20it%20%2A%20the%20floor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cthrew%20it%20%2A%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthrew%20it%20on%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthrew%20it%20to%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthrew%20it%20upon%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthrew%20it%20onto%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthrew%20it%20across%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthrew%20it%20at%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthrew%20it%20along%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthrew%20it%20against%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthrew%20it%20in%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthrew%20it%20into%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0)", "[hurled it * the floor](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hurled%20it%20%2A%20the%20floor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Churled%20it%20%2A%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhurled%20it%20to%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhurled%20it%20on%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhurled%20it%20upon%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhurled%20it%20at%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhurled%20it%20onto%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhurled%20it%20across%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhurled%20it%20against%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0)", and "[flung it * the floor](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flung%20it%20%2A%20the%20floor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cflung%20it%20%2A%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bflung%20it%20on%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflung%20it%20to%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflung%20it%20upon%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflung%20it%20across%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflung%20it%20onto%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflung%20it%20at%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0)".